# C++: Selecting a Derived Class through a Base Using Overloading instead of Dynamic Cast

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, software-design, virtual-functions

As an example to my question, imagine a base class like so:

```cpp
struct Agent {

    void compete(const Agent& competitor) const = 0;

};
```

Associated with a derived like this:

```cpp
struct RockAgent;
struct PaperAgent;

struct ScissorsAgent: public Agent {

    void compete(const Agent& competitor) const override {
        if(dynamic_cast<const RockAgent*>(&competitor))
            std::cout << "I have lost" << std::endl;

        else if(dynamic_cast<const PaperAgent*>(&competitor))
            std::cout << "I have won!" << std::endl;

        //etc....
    }

};
```

And compare it to this base:

```cpp
struct PaperAgent;
struct RockAgent;
struct ScissorsAgent;

struct Agent {

    void compete(const PaperAgent& competitor) const = 0;
    void compete(const RockAgent& competitor) const = 0;
    void compete(const ScissorsAgent& competitor) const = 0;

};
```

and this derived:

```cpp
//forward needed classes.....

struct PaperAgent: public Agent {

    void compete(const PaperAgent& competitor) const override {
        std::cout << "I have won!" << std::endl;
    }

    //etc......

};
```

If I try to use these two methods by passing to the compete() function an Agent polymorphic instance (reference in this case) only the first one compiles. In the second case, the compiler complains that there is no such function as compete(const Agent&). I understand why this does not work, but is there any alternative out there that does not require dynamic_cast and is closer to the second case showed above in terms of design? Maybe a design pattern that I'm not aware of, or that I've never imagined could be used to emulate this?

Comment: You might find "double dispatch" useful

Comment: Is there any reason you just don't make it a virtual function that takes no parameters and have virtual dispatch call the right function?

Comment: My sincere thanks to Justin and double dispatch :) it was exacltly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `Agent`:

```
struct Agent {
  virtual void competeWith(const Agent& competitor) const = 0;
  void compete(const Agent& competitor) const { compeditor.competeWith(*this); }
  virtual void compete(const PaperAgent& competitor) const = 0;
  virtual void compete(const RockAgent& competitor) const = 0;
  virtual void compete(const ScissorsAgent& competitor) const = 0;
};
```

In PaperAgent:

```
struct PaperAgent: public Agent {
  void competeWith(const Agent& competitor) const override final {
    compeditor.compete(*this);
  }
  void compete(const PaperAgent& competitor) const final override;
  void compete(const RockAgent& competitor) const final override;
  void compete(const ScissorsAgent& competitor) const final override;
```

};

this may be helped with the crtp:

```
template<class D>
struct AgentImpl: public Agent 
  void competeWith(const Agent& competitor) const override final {
    compeditor.compete(*static_cast<D const*>(this));
  }
};
struct PaperAgent: public AgentImpl<PaperAgent>{
  void compete(const PaperAgent& competitor) const final override;
  void compete(const RockAgent& competitor) const final override;
  void compete(const ScissorsAgent& competitor) const final override;
};
```

to reduce code replication.

`a1.compete(Agent const& a2)` invokes `a2.competeWith(a1)`, which in turn invokes `a1.compete(a2)` using the dynamic type of `a2` and full overload resolution.

This is one of many standard ways to do "double dispatch" -- acting virtually on two arguments at once.

Comment: In the second block of code that you posted, did you mean to write "const WhateverAgent& competitor" (with WhateverAgent being any child of Agent, like RockAgent or PaperAgent) instead of "const Agent& competitor"? Otherwise the program would just enter a loop the way I understood it... then maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: @dincio we keep the other pure virtual overloads of `compete` within `Agent`, and implememt them in leaf classes.  The above is in addition.  Which is why I said "add".  Copied your original methods in and removed "add" to make it more clear.